# Small table has very high cost in query plan

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue with a query where the query plan says that 15% of the execution cost is for one table. However, this table is very small (only 9 rows).

Clearly there is a problem if the smallest table involved in the query has the highest cost.

My guess is that the query keeps on looping over the same table again and again, rather than caching the results.

What can I do about this?

Sorry, I can't paste the exact code (which is quite complex), but here is something similar:

```
SELECT Foo.Id
FROM Foo
-- Various other joins have been removed for the example
LEFT OUTER JOIN SmallTable as st_1 ON st_1.Id = Foo.SmallTableId1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SmallTable as st_2 ON st_2.Id = Foo.SmallTableId2
WHERE (
    -- various where clauses removed for the example
)
AND (st_1.Id is null OR st_1.Code = 7)
AND (st_2.Id is null OR st_2.Code = 4)
```

Comment: Could you check execution plan? Do you see any table spool? Lookup? How about any index on that table?

Comment: let me take a guess, um...may the statistic of tables didn't get update. The optimizer/query plan might be not proper query plan forthe query.

Answer (score 2):

Take these execution-plan statistics with a wee grain of salt.  If this table is "disproportionately small," relative to all the others, then those cost-statistics probably don't actually mean a hill o' beans.

I mean... think about it ... **:-)** ... if it's a tiny table, what actually *is* it?  Probably, "it's one lousy 4K storage-page in a file somewhere."  We read it in once, and we've got it, period.  End of story.  Nothing (actually...) there to index; no (actual...) *need* to index it; and, at the end of the day, the DBMS will understand this just as well as we do.  Don't worry about it.

Now, having said *that* ... one more thing:  make sure that the "cost" which seems to be attributed to "the tiny table" is not *actually* being incurred by very-expensive access to the tables to which it is *joined.*  If **those** tables don't have decent indexes, or if the query as-written isn't able to make effective use of them, then *there's* your actual problem; *that's* what the query optimizer is actually trying to tell you.  ("It's just a computer ... backwards things says it sometimes.")

Comment: Yes I presume the problem is with the table that it is joined to... I assume what is happening is that it is scanning the contents of this small table N times, where N is the number of rows in the larger table. Like you say though, it could be a red herring. I should just forget about this small table and concentrate my attention elsewhere.

Comment: Well you shouldn't forget about the table altogether, if it's 15% of the total execution, that's significant, even if it is a tiny table.  I think you are correct in that it is likely being scanned many times due to another join, but SQL Server will not purposely decide to scan an object thousands of times, if it's doing that then there is a problem somewhere else in the plan.  Again, the key is looking at estimates vs. actuals as I mentioned in my answer.  When the actual is much higher than the estimated, you can guarantee your plan is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Without the query plan it's difficult to solve your problem here, but there is one glaring clue in your example:

```
AND (st_1.Id is null OR st_1.Code = 7) 
AND (st_2.Id is null OR st_2.Code = 4)
```

This is going to be incredibly difficult for SQL Server to optimize because it's nearly impossible to accurately estimate the cardinality.  Hover over the elements of your query plan and look at EstimatedRows vs. ActualRows and EstimatedExecutions vs. ActualExecutions.  My guess is these are way off.

Not sure what the whole query looks like, but you might want to see if you can rewrite it as two queries with a UNION operator rather than using the OR logic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the limited information available, all I can suggest is that you ensure all columns being used for comparisons are properly indexed.

In addition, you haven't stated if you have an actual performance *problem.* Even if those table accesses took up 90% of the query time, it's most likely not a problem if the query only takes (for example) a tenth of a second.

Comment: Yes I am tuning the query because it is running slowly (5 seconds).